# I get an installation error, when trying to install Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I am typing `npm install -g firebase-tools` but terminal gives me this message:

> checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm
>   ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  {
>   [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] npm ERR!   stack: npm ERR!    'Error:
>   EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'access', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR!
>   It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as
>   the current user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a
>   permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the
>   file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the
>   command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/skltn/.npm/_logs/2018-07-08T19_03_42_011Z-debug.log
>   Skeletons-MacBook-Pro:~ skltn$ firebase --help
>   -bash: firebase: command not found Skeletons-MacBook-Pro:~ skltn$ firebase -login
>   -bash: firebase: command not found Skeletons-MacBook-Pro:~ skltn$ npm install -g firebase-tools npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write
>   access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! path
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! errno -13
>   npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied,
>   access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] npm ERR!
>   stack: npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'', npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!
>   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'access', npm ERR!   path:
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was
>   rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not
>   have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please
>   double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing
>   directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as
>   root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /Users/skltn/.npm/_logs/2018-07-08T19_05_23_066Z-debug.log
>   Skeletons-MacBook-Pro:~ skltn$

Comment: Did u tried with sudo?

Answer (score 2):

This is a permission error, you should use `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates a permission issue, and it's suggesting that you use the sudo command to install firebase-tools globally using npm. To make it more intuitive, you can rephrase it like this:

"To resolve this permission error, please try running the following command with administrator privileges using '**sudo**' to install '**firebase-tools**' globally with npm:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Using 'sudo' grants the necessary permissions to install the tool globally. After running this command, you should be able to use 'firebase-tools' without any permission-related issues."